# How can we read/listen a UDP port in linux server and save the incoming data to MYSQL DB

Tags: php, udp

Using PHP,  how can we read/listen a UDP port in Linux server and save the incoming data to MYSQL database. Is it possible to set a PHP file as a cron/Daemon to do this task. How can we do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to listen an UDP with php you can use [sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php). There is a good example to start with. And about your second question, yes, you can use either cron launch of your script or php like a [daemon](http://phpdaemon.net/).

Comment: Created a php file with the following code and updated as cron job. But data is not getting updated to database. Works fine when we access the file via browser and send data to UDP port.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.0', 9091);

$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 50, 0, $from, $port);

echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" ;
//11111_data

mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") ;
mysql_select_db("ek_database") ;

$pro_data="insert into 11111_data (`data`) values ('$buff')";
mysql_query($pro_data);

Comment: can you make sure that data are coming correctly from UDP source? Maybe there is a database related error.